# handling json response Observable swift

Tags: swift, rx-swift, swifty-json, codable, moya

I have an application which uses SwiftyJSON and works. How ever, I now want to expand the project and refactor the codes but I am having a bit of issue as I am now switching to Codable and I need to be able to mapJSON from any path and not a hard coded path. Currently my jsonResponse looks like this

```
/// handle the network response and map to JSON
    /// - returns: Observable<JSON>
    func handleResponseMapJSON() -> Observable<Result<JSON, ORMError>> {

        return self.map { representor in

            guard let response = representor as? Moya.Response else {
                return .failure(ORMError.ORMNoRepresentor)
            }

            guard ((200...299) ~= response.statusCode) else {
                return .failure(ORMError.ORMNotSuccessfulHTTP)
            }

            guard let json = JSON.init(rawValue: response.data),
                json != JSON.null,
                let code = json["code"].int else {
                    return .failure(ORMError.ORMParseJSONError)
            }

            guard code == BizStatus.BizSuccess.rawValue else {
                let message: String = {
                    let json = JSON.init(data: response.data)
                    guard let msg = json["status"].string else { return "" }
                    return msg
                }()
                log(message, .error)
                return .failure(ORMError.ORMBizError(resultCode: "\(code)", resultMsg: message))
            }

            return .success(json["result"])

        }
    }
```

how do I eliminate the passage of hardcoded `json[""]` value. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try something like this:

```
protocol ResponseType: Codable {
    associatedtype ResultType
    var status: String { get }
    var code: Int { get }
    var result: ResultType { get }
}

func handleResponseMap<T, U>(for type: U.Type) -> (Any) -> Result<T, ORMError> where U: ResponseType, T == U.ResultType {
    return { representor in
        guard let response = representor as? Moya.Response else {
            return .failure(.ORMNoRepresentor)
        }
        guard ((200...299) ~= response.statusCode) else {
            return .failure(.ORMNotSuccessfulHTTP)
        }
        return Result {
            try JSONDecoder().decode(U.self, from: response.data)
            }
            .mapError { _ in ORMError.ORMParseJSONError }
            .flatMap { (response) -> Result<T, ORMError> in
                guard response.code == BizStatus.BizSuccess.rawValue else {
                    log(response.status, .error)
                    return Result.failure(ORMError.ORMBizError(resultCode: "\(response.code)", resultMsg: response.status))
                }
                return Result.success(response.result)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can map directly to your Codable type:

```
let result = self.map(handleResponseMap(for: MyResponse.self))
```

In the above, result will end up being an `Observable<Result<ResultType, ORMError>>`

Comment: This throws an error `In argument type 'User.Type', 'User' does not conform to expected type 'ResponseType'`

Comment: I have created a gist containing the code with `swiftyJson`  https://gist.github.com/AdieOlami/ae4fb3ff70abdb576fe4842afebbbf2d and the Codable that I am trying to achieve

Comment: The conform User to ResponseType or make a new type that conforms to ResponseType and has a User as it's ResultType.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to do extension over `PrimitiveSequenceType` to treat it as `Single`

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import Moya

 public extension PrimitiveSequenceType where TraitType == SingleTrait, ElementType == Response {
    func map<T>(_ type: T.Type, using decoder: JSONDecoder? = nil) -> PrimitiveSequence<TraitType, T> where T: Decodable {
        return self.map { data -> T in
            let decoder = decoder ?? JSONDecoder()
            return try decoder.decode(type, from: data.data)
        }
    }
}
```

and you can simply use it like:

```
return  PokeAPIEndPoints.shared.provider.rx
        .request(.specieDetails(id: specieId))
        .filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
        .map(SpecieDetails.self)
```

Comment: I want to address the error and pass success value in the extension

Comment: I have created a gist containing the code with `swiftyJson`  https://gist.github.com/AdieOlami/ae4fb3ff70abdb576fe4842afebbbf2d and the Codable that I am trying to achieve

Comment: you already using RxSwift which it carries the error for you. and for the result, you specify it in the type of the type method. if you want to make a custom error check you can do something similar what it's mentioned above with a new method `filterServerError` any name you will like and simply throw error there and RxSwift will carry it for you to be received by the subscriber.